# Is there a way to name each JSONObject in an array?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
  "Object1": {
    "description": "An object",
    "data": "more data"
  },
  "Object2": {
    "description": "An object",
    "data": "more data"
  }
}
```

How would I use GSON to iterate over the elements in this JSON Object to easily parse each element one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the man page and found I could loop over the set of members in the object.

```
JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, JsonObject.class);
for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> element : obj.entrySet()) {
    Object obj = gson.fromJson(element.getValue(), Object.class);
    // do stuff with the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but PrabhakarP is right, associative arrays in JSON are objects. So in your case,

```
{
  "Object1": {
    "description": "An object",
    "data": "more data"
  }
}
```

You would have a meta-object containing each array element as a property, which doesn't really make sense. You should parse it differently.

But if you still need, in GSON, then try ,

```
 JsonArray body = gson.fromJson(yourString, JsonArray.class);
        JSONObject metaObj = new JSONObject();  

        for (JsonElement currEle : paymentsArray) {
            JSONObject currObj = currEle.getAsJsonObject();
            String nameVal = currObj.get("name");
            currObj.remove("name");
            metaObj.addProperty(nameVal, currObj);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a property to each object in array and use it